# How can I tell about thing that it is started on the past, and we still doing it until now, and it we will continue do it

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, future

I want to shortly tell some one about a task, assigned to us as a team, 
that we started doing the task, and yet we are doing it and will continue to it.

as example:

> The development started last week of June upto this moment, and will
>   continue until end of august.

OR

> The development started last week of June, and will continue until
>   next week.

OR

> The development started last week of June continuously until
>   next week.

OR

> The development started last week of June until moment, and
>   continuously  til end of august.

what would be the best short expressing sentence?

Comment: I suggest you check the grammar in Word or elsewhere first. especially: last week of June in your context.

Comment: @Lambie: Never tell people to check grammar in Word; its grammar check functionality is pathetic. My copy of Word likes the OP's second sentence fine.

Comment: @PeterShor You're right, it didn't even catch the "the". It is pathetic. My deepest bow. :)

Comment: I will go with the second option @PeterShor

Comment: I would suggest a tweak to the second sentence, however: *The development started* ***in the*** *last week of June, and* ***it*** *will continue until next week.*

Answer (score 1):

> The development started last week of June, and will continue until
>   next week.

With grammatical changes I would say:

X started in the last week of June and will continue until Y.

Answer (score 0):

> that we started doing the task, and yet we are doing it and will continue to it.

Once communicated that the task has been started, it is redundant to state that the task is still ongoing. Thus, the quickest way to state your question would be one of your suggestions:

> The development team started last week of June and will continue until next week.

I omitted the Oxford comma, but is correct with it as well.

Now, if the context of this statement necessitates highlighting that the task is currently in progress, I would recommend omitting having to state that it has been started -- that would then be redundant. Suggested phrasing would be:

> The development team is currently working on the task and will continue until next week.